# How to get a value of a dictionary within a list of dictionaries when the dict equals a certain name?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, format

I want to retrieve certain values from a list object that contains strings and dictionaries. If the dictionary equals a certain name I want to add it to the output file.

First I read in a json file which looks like this:

```
    {
      "event": "user",
      "timestamp": {
        "$numberDouble": "1671459681.4369426"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "model_id": "125817626"
      },
      "text": "hello",
      "parse_data": {
        "intent": {
          "name": "greet",
          "confidence": {
            "$numberDouble": "1.0"
          }
        },
```

I have events that equal "user" and those that equal "bot". What I want to have in the end is an output file that has user and bot in each line. At the beginning of the line I also want to have the timestamp, formatted in human readable time, and at the end the text like

> 2020-03-13 12:11:25 user: hello

> 2020-03-13 12:11:28 bot: Hi

However, I do not know how to access the value of "timestamp", format it and then print it together with "user" and "text" in one line.

What I have done so far is that:

```
     import json
     from datetime import datetime

     f = open('1234.json')
  
     data = json.load(f)
     all_events = [e for e in data.get('events', list()) if e.get('event')=='user' or e.get('event')=='bot']

     file_object = open('1234.txt', 'a')
     for event in all_events:
         file_object.write(str(event.get('timestamp'))+ " "+ event.get('event')+ ": " + event.get('text', '')+ "\n")

     f.close()
```

What I get with this is:

> {'$numberDouble': '1671459681.4369426'} user: hello

I know that I can use something like this to format the time

```
      ts = int("1584101485")
      print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

But I do not know how to wrap this in my file_object.write command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the `timestamp` key's value, you need to parse the `$numberDouble` value inside of the `timestamp` dictionary:

```py
file_object.write(
    datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(event['timestamp']['$numberDouble'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + " "+ event.get('event')+ ": " + event.get('text', '')+ "\n"
)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! Also for the explanation!